# The non-existence of a matrix $A\in M_3(\mathbb{R})$ such that $A^2-A+I=0$.

Tags: linear-algebra, vector-spaces, vectors, linear-transformations

I'm trying to get my head around this problem, which states that no $3\times 3$ real-valued matrix can satisfy the equation $$A^2-A+I=0.$$ 
Of course, the problem is trivial if we consider characteristic polynomials and eigenvalues, but I want to prove it in the most elementary way possible, just basic theory of matrix operations and vector spaces. So considering the polynomial $p(λ):=\det (A-λI)$ without mentioning the word "eigenvalue" isn't good enough.

The only thing I can get out of this equation is that the matrix must be invertible and its inverse will be $A^{-1} = I-A$ and other deceptively useful identities, but I can't move on in any way.

Any hints are appreciated!

Comment: The secret phrase is *companion matrix*.

Comment: @GerryMyerson I have no knowledge on that matter and from what I see on wiki, I don't see the exact relevance! Could you elaborate? Thank you!

Comment: The companion matrix of a polynomial $p(x)$ is an example of a matrix $A$ such that $p(A)=0$.

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Finding the Matrix of a Linear Operator Satisfying a Polynomial](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3714133/finding-the-matrix-of-a-linear-operator-satisfying-a-polynomial)

Comment: @Carlo almost! the answer given there, even without mentioning the words "characteristic polynomial" and "eigenvalues" isn't as elementary as I please. Why should one consider the polynomial in the first place when he doesn't have any idea about eigenvalues and what do they mean? ;)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No such linear map exists. Suppose the contrary. Then $p(A)=0$ where $p(x)=x^2-x+1$. Pick any vector $v\ne0$. There are two possibilities:

1. $Av=cv$ for some $c\in\mathbb R$. Then $0=p(A)v=p(c)v$ and hence $p(c)=0$.
2. $V=\operatorname{span}\{v,Av\}$ is two-dimensional. Then $\mathbb R^3=V\oplus\operatorname{span}\{u\}$ for some $u\not\in V$ and
   $$
   Au=v_1+cu
   $$
   for some $v_1\in V$ and $c\in\mathbb R$. Since $A^2=A-I$, we have $A\{v,Av\}\subseteq V$. Hence $AV\subseteq V$ and in particular, $Av_1\in V$. It follows that
   \begin{align}
   A^2u=A(v_1+cu)=v_2+c^2u\tag{1}
   \end{align}
   for some $v_2\in V$. However, we also have
   \begin{align}
   A^2u=Au-u=v_1+(c-1)u.\tag{2}
   \end{align}
   By comparing the coefficients of $v$ in $(1)$ and $(2)$, we obtain $p(c)=0$.

Thus we arrive at contradictions in both cases, because $p(x)=0$ has not any real root. Hence $p(A)$ is never zero and $f$ does not exist.

Comment: Awesome solution, thank you very much!