# Finding the Matrix of a Linear Operator Satisfying a Polynomial

Tags: linear-algebra, matrices, minimal-polynomials

This question has been doing my head in, as it limits us to not use eigenvalues, diagonalization or anything analogous -- just strictly linear functions.

> Given a linear function $f : \mathbb R^3 \to \mathbb R^3$ that satisfies $p(x) = x^2 - x + 1,$ find the matrix $A$ of $f$ with respect to the standard basis of $\mathbb R^3$

Comment: Is this even possible? Such a matrix would have to have only eigenvalues $(1 \pm \sqrt{3}i )/2$, which can’t happen if the matrix is real. Have I missed something?

Comment: @paulinho Yes, such a thing cannot happen, but we need to illustrate it.

Comment: @Snob Do you know that operators on real odd-dimensional spaces always have at least one (real) eigenvalue?

Comment: For the $2 \times 2$ problem, one standard solution to such a problem is to use the [companion matrix](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Companion_matrix) of the polynomial $p(x) = x^2 - x + 1$, namely
$$
A = \pmatrix{0&-1\\1&1}.
$$

Answer (score 1):

I'm not sure how restrictive "diagonalization or anything analogous" is supposed to be, but here's one argument that such a linear transformation cannot exist.

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ satisfies $p(f) = 0$. Because $\Bbb R^3$ is a space of odd dimension, $f$ necessarily has a real eigenvalue. That is, there exists a non-zero $x \in \Bbb R^3$ and a $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ for which $f(x) = \lambda x$.  Now, note that
$$
p(f) = 0 \implies [p(f)](x) = 0 \implies p(\lambda)x = 0 \implies p(\lambda) = 0.
$$
However, the polynomial $p(x)$ has no real roots, so we have a contradiction.

So, no such $f$ exists.

---

A proof of the existence of a real eigenvalue, from scratch.  We consider the characteristic polynomial of $A$, $p_A(t) = \det(tI - A)$. From the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for the derivative, we see that $p_A(t)$ must have degree $3$ because the sum contains the term $(t-a_{11})(t-a_{22})(t-a_{33})$, and each term in the sum is a product of $3$ terms with degree at most $1$.

Because $p_A(t)$ is a degree $3$ polynomial, it necessarily has a real root. In particular, it suffices to note that $\lim_{t \to -\infty}p_A(t)$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} p_A(t)$ have opposite signs, so that $p_A$ must have a real root by the intermediate value theorem.

So, let $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ be such that $p_A(\lambda) = 0$. Because $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$, the matrix $\lambda I - A$ must have a non-trival nullspace. That is, the exists a non-zero vector $x$ for which 
$$
(\lambda I - A)x = 0 \implies \lambda I x = Ax \implies Ax = \lambda x.
$$
In other words, $A$ necessarily has a real eigenvalue $\lambda$.

---

An writeup of the proof that makes no use of the terms "characteristic polynomial" or "eigenvalue".

Suppose that $f:\Bbb R^3 \to \Bbb R^3$ satisfies $p(f) = 0$, and let $A$ be its matrix.  We consider the function $q(t) = \det(tI - A)$. From the [Leibniz formula](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Leibniz_formula_for_determinants) for the derivative, we see that $q(t)$ must be a polynomial degree  $3$ because the sum contains the term $(t-a_{11})(t-a_{22})(t-a_{33})$, and each term in the sum is a product of $3$ terms with degree at most $1$.

Because $q(t)$ is a degree $3$ polynomial, it necessarily has a real root. In particular, it suffices to note that $\lim_{t \to -\infty}q(t)$ and $\lim_{t \to \infty} q(t)$ have opposite signs, so that $q$ must have a real root by the intermediate value theorem.

So, let $\lambda \in \Bbb R$ be such that $q(\lambda) = 0$. Because $\det(\lambda I - A) = 0$, the matrix $\lambda I - A$ must have a non-trival nullspace. That is, the exists a non-zero vector $x$ for which 
$$
(\lambda I - A)x = 0 \implies \lambda I x = Ax \implies Ax = \lambda x.
$$
Now, note that
$$
p(A) = 0 \implies [p(A)](x) = 0 \implies p(\lambda)x = 0 \implies p(\lambda) = 0.
$$
However, the polynomial $p(x)$ has no real roots, so we have a contradiction. So, no such $f$ exists.

Comment: I'm sorry, no eigenvalues allower either, made an edit to the question. Thanks for the attempt!

Comment: @Snob what about determinants?

Comment: Please do, (this is here to add characters)

Comment: @Snob see my latest edit.

Comment: Did, and the only proof one must provide cannot mention anything that cannot be understood from someone that knows nothing from eigenvalues, or characteristic polynomials. This is supposed to be able to be shown with very basic linear algebra. I really enjoy the proof though.

Comment: @Snob we don't need to mention the terms "characteristic polynomial", "eigenvalue", or "eigenvector". The proof is self contained.

Comment: @Snob again, see my latest edit.

Comment: I might be missing something, but you do mention the term characteristic polynomial.

Comment: @Snob Do I mention it in the proof that I wrote in the third section?

Comment: No you did not, thank you very much for your time!